# Spring-Batch: How to read encrypted XML file node by node using StaxEventReader

Tags: spring-batch, public-key-encryption

I am developing one Migration Utility which reads data from XML and migrate to ORACLE database.

I am using Spring Batch.

My source XML can be at any location :

- Classpath location
- Shared Network Location

My Spring Batch configuration is

```
<batch:job id="reportJob">
        <batch:step id="step1">
            <batch:tasklet>
                <batch:chunk reader="xmlItemReader" writer="oracleDBWriter"
                    processor="filterReportProcessor" commit-interval="1">
                </batch:chunk>
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>

    <bean id="filterReportProcessor" class="com.mkyong.processor.FilterReportProcessor" />

    <bean id="xmlItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader">
        <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="record" />
        <property name="resource" value="classpath:xml/report.xml" />
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="reportUnmarshaller" />
    </bean>
```

I am able to read XML and dumps to DB.

One of change is XML file will not be in plain format, it will be encrypted using Asymmetric algorithm (public-private key).

So I am wondering that I will not be able to use **StaxEventItemReader** to read node by node.
and before that I am not aware how to

- decrypt file
- Read node by node.

I was looking to use ByteArrayResource but not able to do that as m new to spring batch and have not so much idea of extension.

Please suggest.

Comment: Are you planning on encrypting the entire file or just the values within it?

Comment: entire file will be encrypted, data inside XML is in plain file and thats'y want to encrypt a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Batch currently doesn't support decryption while reading.  Because of that, you'd need to do a separate step of decrypting the file before processing it.  Obviously you'll need the appropriate controls around the removal of the decrypted file once processing is complete.

Comment: What I am doing right now.. I have extended org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader<T> and override org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader.doOpen() method first to decrypt the file and set back whole decrypted string to its property org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader.inputStream . Am I doing right ?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that approach.  A less invasive approach would be to use a `StepExecutionListener` to encrypt the file at the beginning of the step and then use the afterStep method to delete the unencrypted file.

Comment: I have not deleted the file, what I am doing, 1. Decrypt file 2. Getting plain string representation of decrypted XML 3. Initialize Input stream from decrypted string content, 4. Delegate that input stream back to StaxEventReader... will try to use Listener but i think in listener too , I need to do mentioned 4 steps in order to read fragment by fragment XML

Comment: I want to use StepExecutionListener to decrypt file first and get few content from it.but How can I read source XML file in StepExecutionListener? My Reader configuration is <bean id="xmlItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader">
  <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="userDetail" />
  <property name="resource" value="classpath:XML_Structure.xml" />
  <property name="unmarshaller" ref="userDetailUnmarshaller" />
 </bean>

Comment: You'll need to inject it just like you inject it into your reader.